Jobs for philosophy majors - who is hiring?

Philosophy graduates are found working for almost every type of
employer in the public, private and not-for-profit sectors.
Opportunities are available in areas like publishing, the media,
journalism, advertising and teaching, through to computing and IT
https://www.prospects.ac.uk/careers-advice/what-can-i-do-with-my-degree/philosophy#:~:text=Philosophy%20graduates%20are%20found%20working,through%20to%20computing%20and%20IT.

In philosophy, everything can also mean nothing.
Does anybody have experience working for large corporations with a degree in philosophy?

For many jobs, just having a degree in something helps your resume. I can't think of many things where philosophy specifically would help, except to teach philosophy.

@andrós - This is what they say: philosophers are everywhere. But this answer is too philosophical.

A degree in philosophy may help indirectly in some jobs - in so far as it may mean you have acquired good, general analytical skills, skills in analysing/interpreting language. You'd still need the extra technical expertise too, however - if want to pass an interview as software dev for instance...

@mudskipper which is what a colleague did: at Cantab switched from Natural Sciences to Philosophy, had a helluva 3 years instead of hard graft, graduated and got a job writing financial software in the City (of London).

@WeatherVane - Natural Sciences: hard graft, Philosophy: helluva. The Brits are definitely different from the Yankees.

Maybe he was able to blag it. He said that he saw it would be impossible to graduate without that graft, whereas he had already read and knew much of the Philosophy course's material.

This probably belongs on [academics.SE] or [workplace.SE]
